# How can I get response from guzzle 6 in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, guzzle, guzzle6

I read from here : http://www.phplab.info/categories/laravel/consume-external-api-from-laravel-5-using-guzzle-http-client

I try like this :

```
...
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleHttpClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
...
public function testApi()
{
    try {
        $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
        $apiRequest = $client->request('POST', 'https://myshop/api/auth/login', [
            // 'query' => ['plain' => 'Ab1L853Z24N'],
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'auth' => ['test@gmail.com', '1234'],       //If authentication required
            // 'debug' => true                                  //If needed to debug   
        ]);
        $content = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody()->getContents());
        dd($content);
    } catch (RequestException $re) {
          //For handling exception
    }
}
```

When executed, the result is null

How can I get the response?

I try in postman, it success get response

But I try use guzzle, it failed

**Update :**

I check on the postman, the result works

I try click button code on the postman

Then I select php curl and I copy it, the result like this :

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://myshop/api/auth/login",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\ntest@gmail.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n1234\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    "postman-token: 1122334455-abcd-edde-aabe-adaddddddddd"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

If it use curl php, the code like that

How can I get the response if it use guzzle?

Comment: Why my question is downvote? Is there a mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see at least one syntax mistake. The third argument of the `request()` method should look like this:

```
$requestContent = [
    'headers' = [],
    'json' = []
];
```

In your case it could be:

```
public function testApi()
{
    $requestContent = [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'json' => [
            'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
            'password' => '1234',
            // 'debug' => true
        ]
    ];

    try {
        $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();

        $apiRequest = $client->request('POST', 'https://myshop/api/auth/login', $requestContent);

        $response = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody());

        dd($response);
    } catch (RequestException $re) {
          // For handling exception.
    }
}
```

There are other parameters instead of `json` for your data, for example `form_params`. I suggest you take a look at [the Guzzle documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#post-form-requests).

Comment: Should $httpContent changed to be $requestContent

Comment: The result is empty

Comment: Yes, it's the same

Comment: This is strange. I use postman and phpcurl, it can get response. There seems to be a code that needs to be added

Comment: When you use Postman, what kind of body do you use? `form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Can you show us (e.g. a screenshot) the part where you declare the body in Postman please?

Comment: Ah you got ahead of me :) Okay then the problem is just that you are not formating your request correctly with Guzzle. Check my updated answer.

Comment: It's the same. I use guzzle 6. Maybe the problem is syntax writing

Comment: Are you **really** sending the request as I wrote it in my answer? Because it works on my side.